# R Markdown document crops code snippets in PDF output

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

The following header is from a R Markdown document which I have compiled as a PDF. It results in code snippets being cropped. Commenting out the PDF output block and uncommenting the HTML block results in well-formatted HTML output.

**Is there a parameter I can change to fix this? Or do I need to format my code snippets differently?**

```
---
title: "fmodbc Package"
author: "Bobby Rohrkemper, Software Developer at Schweiz Tourismus"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
# output: 
#   rmarkdown::html_vignette:
#     toc: TRUE
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: TRUE
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Vignette Title}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

Or should I perhaps try a different theme? I would be interested in the Tufte Handout theme, but thought it makes more sense to fix the standard output first.

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/tufte_handout_format.html

#### PDF output is cropped:

[image: PDF output is cropped]

#### HTML output looks good:

[image: HTML output looks good]

#### Code snippet:

This produces the results above. I am not modifying it in the PDF and HTML versions.

````
```{r}
# names(dat)
# "__Backups"              "__Budget"               "__Comments"             "__Documents"            "__globals"              "__KPI"           "__Marketing Activities" "__MarketManager"        "__Segmentation"         "__sts_Account"          "__sts_Budget"           "__sts_Mandate"    "__sts_ProfitCenter"     "__UserLog"              "__VL_PlanningStatus"   
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Use the chunk option `tidy = TRUE`.

> tidy: (FALSE; logical) whether R code should be tidied up using the function tidy_source() in the formatR package; if it failed to tidy up, original R code will not be changed; tidy=TRUE is like keep.source=FALSE in Sweave, but it also tries not to discard R comments (N.B. this option does not work in certain cases; see http://yihui.name/formatR for more information)

````
---
title: "fmodbc Package"
author: "Bobby Rohrkemper, Software Developer at Schweiz Tourismus"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
# output: 
#   rmarkdown::html_vignette:
#     toc: TRUE
output:
  pdf_document:
      toc: TRUE
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Vignette Title}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(tidy = TRUE)
```


```{r}
# names(dat)
# "__Backups"              "__Budget"               "__Comments" "__Documents"            "__globals"              "__KPI"           "__Marketing Activities" "__MarketManager"        "__Segmentation"         "__sts_Account" "__sts_Budget"           "__sts_Mandate"    "__sts_ProfitCenter"     "__UserLog" "__VL_PlanningStatus"   
```
````

[image]